# How do I switch primary domains with the API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I found this:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/

But which is the intended method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.customers.update

Specify the required domain as the value against the customerdomain key in the body .